# Convert UIViewController to UIScrollViewController

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uilabel

I am new to iPad developer,

I made one Registration form in my application, when i see my application in `Portrait` mode,
i am able to see whole form with no scrolling, but when i see same form in `Landscape` mode, i am not able to see part which is at bottom of page, for that a scrolling should be there to see bottom part.

[image: s]:
In my `.h` file when i replace

```
@interface ReminderPage : UIViewController{
...
...
}
```

`:UIViewController` with `:UIScrollView`

and then when i add label in my `.m` file like this,

```
UILabel *Lastpaidlbl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70 ,400, 130, 50)]autorelease];
    Lastpaidlbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    Lastpaidlbl.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    Lastpaidlbl.text = @"Lastpaid on :";
    [self.view addSubview:Lastpaidlbl];
```

I am getting error on last line **Property view not found on object of type classname.**
i am unable to add label in my view.

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: Typically you use [camel notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for variable names in Obj-C. It makes it easier for us to read

Comment: If you replace UIViewController with UIScrollView I expect your application will not even compile, and if it does you will get an immediate crash with a blindingly obvious error message. Therefore you can not have done what your question says. Please read about the difference between a view and a view controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to replace your UIViewController with a UIScrollView, you will have to go a bit of refactoring to your code. The error you get is just an example of that:

the syntax:

```
[self.view addSubview:Lastpaidlbl];
```

is correct if `self` is a UIViewController; since you changed it to be `UIScrollView`, you should now do:

```
[self addSubview:Lastpaidlbl];
```

You will have quite a few changes like this one to make to your code and will face some issues.

Another approach would be this:

1. instantiate a UIScrollView (not derive from it);
2. add your UIView (such as you have defined it) to the scroll view;
3. define the `contentSize` of the scroll view so to include the whole UIView you have.

The scroll view acts as a container for your existing view (you add your controls to the scroll view, then add the scroll view to self.view); this way, you could integrate it within your existing controller:

```
      1. UIScrollView* scrollView = <alloc/init>

      2. [self.view addSubview:scrollView]; (in your  controller)

      3. [scrollView addSubview:<label>]; (for all of your labels and fields).

      4. scrollView.contentSize = xxx;
```

I think the latter approach will be much easier.

Answer (score 6):

The question appears to be really asking how can all the components on the screen be placed inside a UIScrollView, rather than a UIView.  Using Xcode 4.6.3, I found I could achieve this by simply:

- In Interface Builder, select all the sub-views inside the main UIView.
- Choose Xcode menu item "Editor | Embed In | Scroll View".

The end result was a new scroll view embedded in the existing main UIView, will all the former sub-views of the UIView now as sub-views of the UIScrollView, with the same positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Please put all of your UIComponents to the UIScrollview and then it will start scrolling.

please look in to content size. please change it according to the orientation of device.

Comment: I do not want change size of content according to orientation. i want scroll in view. OR how to add components to UIScrollView ?

Comment: If you are using XIB file take a scroll view and put it outside of main view and make its height larger then screen size put all other ui component to that scroll view . after compeletion of putting UIComponents put the scroll view to mainview. and with the help of inspector define content size . (then there will be no need to change the content size again and again)

Answer (score 0):

You're subclassing `UIScrollView`, so there is no `self.view` because already `self` is the view (of the scrollview). You dont need to subclass the scrollview, you can just embed your components in a ivar scrollview and set its `contentSize` (in your case, you have to enable the scrolling just when the device is in landscape mode). In interface builder you can embed the selected elements in one click, Editor-> Embed in-> scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

First create **scrollview**

```
 UIScrollView *  scr=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 756, 1000)];
    scr.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [ self.view addSubview:scr];
```

**second**

change  `[self.view addSubview:Lastpaidlbl];`

```
      to
```

[scr addSubview:Lastpaidlbl];

**third**

set **height** depends on content

```
UIView *view = nil;

 NSArray *subviews = [scr subviews];


 CGFloat curXLoc = 0;

    for (view in subviews)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        curXLoc += (frame.size.height);
    }
       // set the content size so it can be scrollable
    [scr setContentSize:CGSizeMake(756, curXLoc)];
```

Finally

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        self.scr.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 703,768);    

        } else {
        self.scr.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
        }


    return YES;
}
```